# inotify inconsistent behavior on symbolic links

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I tried inotify calls. It worked ok to follow appending files. However, being requested to monitor change of symbolic link, firstly, I had a hard time to find that the event needed is IN_MOVE_SELF, and then blocking call to read returned not by all actual modification events but by some. So I had to use old sleep/readlink polling design instead.

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: whether i do anything wrong or it's a bug in inotify...

Comment: It's almost certainly not an issue with inode unless you are using a very old kernel/disto.